# Fastest way to move a PostgreSQL database on a remote server

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, psql, pg-dump

I need to move a quite large database of a little more than 100GB from an old remote server to a new remote server.

I am connecting via ssh to the new server and use the following command from there, but I don't think it is the best/fastest way to do it.

```
pg_dump -C -h 123.123.123.123 -U pgadmin -W -d db_name | psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U pgadmin -W -d db_name
```

Is there a better way to do it ? I am thinking about using some sort of data compression in order to reduce the data transferred from the two machines, but I don't know how to do it and if it is useful.

Answer (score 3):

It is going to depend on what the bottleneck is.

You could use `pg_basebackup` instead, which spares you the need to compute the new indexes the way `pg_dump` does.  But, you might be transfering a lot more data, so that could slow you down more than it speeds you up.

If network bandwidth is a severe bottleneck, then you could log onto the source server (123.123.123.123) and do `pg_basebackup -Ft -D- -Xnone ... | pxz > backup.tar.xz`, then use scp or rsync to transfer the compressed data to the new server.  You will have to have a wal archive so the new server can fetch any WAL files it missed.  It might be possible to juggle replication slots so you don't need this, but pg_basebackup doesn't make it easy to do that.

xz is very slow.  pxz is less slow if you have many CPUs, but still pretty slow.  So doing that is only worthwhile is the network is slower still than pxz is.  If the network is not quite that slow, you could use a faster but less thorough compression method, like gzip or its parallel version pigz.

You could also do the same thing with `pg_dump ... | pxz > dump.sql.xz`.

If you don't want so store the compressed file on the original server, you could stream it over the network on the fly, using something like `ssh 123.123.123.123 "pg_dump ...|pxz" | xzcat | psql ...`.  (Or you could do the same thing with pg_basebackup instead).  But the problem here is that you cannot resume from a network glitch, but have to repeat the whole thing from scratch.  That is why I prefer to save the file on the original server if there is room for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a replica and once the databases have aligned, elect the slave (the new replicated one) as master and start writing on this one.

[Here](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/02/21/three-approaches-to-postgresql-replication/), for example,  you can start learning about postgres replication.

Answer (score 0):

steps:

1. allow remote connect on remote server https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection
2. if you using Putty, change 0 to 30 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDcbT.png
3. create database on remote server with name `your_remote_database_name`
4. connect ssh to local server and  `PGPASSWORD="your_local_posgres_user_password" pg_dump -C -h localhost -U postgres your_local_database_name | PGPASSWORD="your_remove_posgres_user_password" psql -h your_remote_ip -U postgres your_remote_database_name`